# Upgrading springboot version from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8 websecurity issue - 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, websecurity

Upgrading from springboot v2.1.7 to v2.1.8, we hit an issue that all endpoints are giving now 401 without logging any errors.

- To put in mind no other changes has been done, it`s only a version bump.
- also to mention that locally when running the springboot app locally all run fine.
  and when deploying on the pre-production environment it just gives 401 for all endpoints

  ```
  my machine is having ubuntu 22.04

  pre-prod machine is having centos ~7.9

  we are using java 8 and tomcat
  ```

here is how is our websecurity looks like ( this file hasn't been touched )

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Value("${roles}")
    public String roles;

    @Value("${security.allowed.ip}")
    private String allowedIp;

    @Value("${web.security.config.web.ignore.matchers}")
    private List<String> webIgnoreMatchers;

    @Value("${web.security.config.http.cors.matchers}")
    private List<String> httpCorsMatchers;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        try {
            web.ignoring()
                    .antMatchers(webIgnoreMatchers.stream().toArray(String[]::new));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/someendpoint").hasIpAddress(allowedIp)
                    .antMatchers(httpCorsMatchers.stream().toArray(String[]::new))
                    .permitAll()
                    .mvcMatchers("/**")
                    .hasAnyAuthority(roles).anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- So after deeper investigation and changing the log level to trace
  We found out that spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri & spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri starting from spring-boot 2.1.8 is no longer supporting http protocol ( on prod deployments )
- So on prod environment u must use https instead, other wise you will get this 401 error instantly